# Android null pointer onDraw Bitmap image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bitmapfactory

I'm having a problem which I can't seem to solve here! I'm developing a simple android game and had pretty much implemented everything, but then decided to add some obstacles in (the game is a lunar lander style game).

Basically, I've created an Asteroid class and am just trying to draw them on the screen. When loading the game the asteroids are drawn, and everything works fine, but if you press the home button or power off and then relaunch the game I get a NPE:

```
03-04 21:33:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(10748): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-680
03-04 21:33:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(10748): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 21:33:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(10748):    at com.swiss196.LunarLander.GameThread.doDraw(GameThread.java:421)
03-04 21:33:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(10748):    at com.swiss196.LunarLander.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:386)
```

And it points to the following code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(test2.getBitmap(), 120, 120, null);
```

Which would suggest either the canvas or the test2 object / image that getBitmap returns is null, but prior to this I check that the canvas is not null. And within bitmap, I check the image is not null either:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
if(asteroidImage == null)
    asteroidImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mGameView.getContext().getResources(),
                                                 R.drawable.asteroid);

return asteroidImage;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If decodeResource returns null (which it will on error) the getBitmap function returns null.  Check that possibility out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd forgotten to reload some of the needed variables from the bundle, including the images..

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably exceeding your memory budget, and that's the reason you're getting a null value when you try to [decode your Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29).

The developer sites have [pretty good descriptions](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) how to avoid this.

One important option to use (look at the second link again for examples how to use it) is the "BitmapFactory.Options" which allow you just to verify if you've got enough memory for your Bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Quoting the documentation

> Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids
>   memory allocation, returning null for the bitmap object but setting
>   outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType. This technique allows you to read
>   the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction (and
>   memory allocation) of the bitmap.

Comment: Surely I would get an `java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.` error?

Comment: Sadly, no. Read the documentation (here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources, int)).

Comment: What you get (if you look for it in the logcat) is the error message. You don't get a catchable Exception, though.